# Using Jenkins and Maven, getting - 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: maven, jenkins

In the Build section, for Execute Windows batch command, I have the following:

```
mvn package
```

Here is the info from Console Output in Jenkins:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Mvn_Web_App>mvn package 
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

My setup is as follows:

- Win10 Pro
- apache-maven-3.6.3
- apache-tomcat-8.5.64
- Jenkins 2.277.1 LTS for Windows

Results for cmd test:

```
C:\Users\username>mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_281, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Installed, configured and input all the settings per seen in other posts.

I even set JDK and Maven under **Global Tool Configuration**


**JDK**

**Name:** jdk8

**JAVA_HOME:** C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281


**Maven**

**Name:** Maven 3.6.3

**MAVEN_HOME:** C:\apache-maven-3.6.3\

**System Variables:**

- JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281
- M2_HOME = C:\apache-maven-3.6.3
- Path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281\bin ; %M2_HOME%\bin

Instead of entering:

```
mvn package
```

I entered

```
C:\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\mvn package
```

And then...IT WORKS!!! Why is that? Where is the disconnect... I cannot find it!

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Mvn_Web_App>C:\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\mvn package 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< jenkins.mvn.demo:mvnwebapp >---------------------
[INFO] Building mvnwebapp Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
```

Comment: If you are using invoke maven top-level targets, you just need "package". If using she'll and calling maven , you need to inject variables for M2_HOME, etc. If pipeline, use withMaven or specify "tools:"